# submit all users values from form into db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, foreach

This gives lists all people in the db and give a drop down for each one of them i want to make it so when i hit one submit button it enters individual values for each person.

so if you make yes for bobby no for mark and yes for dustin you can the pres submit and it will enter that for there values

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$tabeluser` WHERE buss='$buss' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results) )
{   
        fn = $_POST['firstname'];
        echo $fn;
        ?>
        <form>

        <select name="check">
                <option>no</option>
                <option>yes</option>
        </select>
        <?php
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        ?>
        <form>
        <?php
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$fn` (buss) VALUES ('$_POST[check]')");
```

Comment: `this gives lists all people` but how? There are many syntax error. If you have working copy why did not send it?

Comment: As per my understanding you need to save `check` drop-down data with respective user seleted index in db.

Comment: i just wrote it for an example i did not know i showed it as a working copy but i'm just trying to figure out if i have a form that shows multiple people in the db how do i do insert different values for each person using one button

Comment: yes .........................

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you create a `<form>` and a `submit` button **for each** of the records you have. That is wrong, since you want to update multiple values at once.
What it should look like would be:

```
<form>
<?php
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    print '<select name="check[]"> .. </select>';
  }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Secondly, your code is formatted as if you are expecting to get $_POST[check] right after sending the code to the browser. **That is not how PHP works. You need to separate the logic of having posted values, before printing the actual page contents.** PHP is server side, which means that it won't get any data, unless the script is called with it from the beginning. So, that should look something like:

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
     // handle posted data.
   }
   else {
     // show form
   }
   // or show form here, without an else, if you want to always show a form,
   // even when you have posted values.
 ?>
```

Last but not least, you need to find a way to know which posted value belongs to each of your records. The way you have it now (`<select name="check">') it will just return you one single value.

If you write it the way I intentionally did above (``) you will get all values, but still you won't be able to easily recognize which value is for each record.
Instead, you may want to do a final result of something like:

```
<?php
   // get mysql records into an array (say $my_array)
   if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     foreach($my_array as $record) {
       if (isset($_POST["select_of_id_".$record["id"])) {
         // insert additional value into db
       }
     }
   }
   print '<form>';
   foreach($my_array as $record) {
     print '<select name="select_of_id_'.$record["id"].'">';
     print '<option value="0">no</option><option value="1">yes</option>';
     print '</select>';
   }
   print '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
   print '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes required in your code :-

```
<select name="check[]">
            <option value="<?php echo $userId;?>_0">no</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $userId;?>_1">yes</option>
</select>
```

You should make changes in you DB It help to easy maintaing your data.

Create new table where you can save multiple user check data with respective Post

```
for e.g    post_id  user_id   check
            101      111        0
            101      112        1
```

How you can store data from you html

In you post array you will get `check` array in which you will get multiple check value like this

`101_0` if no selected and `102_1` if yes selected. Now you need to explode this value.

```
    $_POST['check'] = array(0 => `101_0`, 1 => 102_1);
```

Inside loop you can extract userid and respective checked value.

for e.g

```
     $checked = explode('_','101_0');
     $userId  = $checked[0];
     $check   =  $checked[1];
```